Dependency conflicts due to Django version
I am currenlty working to integrate azureSQL to my website, but I am encountering this error that some of my packages require django version more than 4, others require version 2, what should I do?
this is the error I am getting :
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
djangorestframework 3.15.2 requires django>=4.2, but you have django 2.1.15 which is incompatible.
django-cors-headers 4.4.0 requires django>=3.2, but you have django 2.1.15 which is incompatible.

I tried downgrading django version but that gave me the same problem but for other packages

so you need at least django>=4.2

either try upgrading django version or downgrade the mentioned dependencies

If you're trying to use packages that have conflicting Django version dependencies, there's not much you can do to magically overcome that, you have to choose between one of the following:

If possible, upgrade the package(s) that require Django 2.x to a version that supports Django 4.2, while naturally also upgrading your installation to Django 4.2
If possible, downgrade the package(s) that require Django 3.x/Django 4.x to versions that are compatible with Django 2.x and continue using Django 2.1.15
Get rid of either the Django >=3.x packages or the Django 2.x packages, and find an alternate solution (either custom functionality or look for different packages) for what those packages were giving you

Moving your code to Django 4.2 (or actually Django >=5.0, if you're first having to take a bigger migration step) is the best bet going forward for a lot of reasons. Chances are that you can find other packages to replicate the functionality of the 2.x-packages - and if you can't, that could be an indicator that the specific workflow they enable is not healthy anymore.
